# Jupyter extension jupyter_scheduler fail to create job

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

After installing the Jupyter extension jupyter_scheduler (1.2.0) with `pip` on my `JupyterHub` server following the [docs](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-scheduler), it is impossible to create a schedule for a notebook.

On creation of a job it shows the message "Unexpected error occurred during creation of job."

Error during job creation

[image: 1]

I verified that both the `jupyter_scheduler` server extension and the `@jupyterlab/scheduler` prebuilt lab extension are indeed enabled. No error message is shown and all looks OK to me.

Any idea how to find more info about the "Unexpected error" in log files or elsewhere is more than welcome.

Comment: Given how recent this extension is I would suggest opening an issue directly on GitHub as there is likely little experience among other users.